# Data export to csv file from database

Tags: php, csv

I have tried to export data from database to csv file using following code.

```
if (isset($_POST['export'])) {
$searchElem = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers;");
$searchElem->execute();
$row= $searchElem->fetchAll();
$file = fopen('demo.csv', 'w');
foreach($row as $result)
{
    fputcsv($file, $result);
}

fclose($file);              
}}
```

It exports the data but each and every data is inserted into file 2 times. How can i solve it? and why is there double quotation in some data?. Like:

```
20000013,20000013,kris,kris,,,sin,sin,,,Male,Male,1997-12-11,1997-12-11,"Gokarna, Kathmandu","Gokarna, Kathmandu"
```

Comment: the double quotes are there because your actual data item contains a comma - if the quotes weren't there, any program opening the CSV would assume the 2 pieces of text either side of the comma were separate columns, which they aren't. PHP does this automatically for you within the fputcsv function. I can't say why the rows are inserted twice, the code looks ok from that perspective. Maybe `$result` already contains all the fields twice, for some reason?

Comment: seems that `fetchAll` gets indexd and assoc values `row = [0=>123,'id'=>123]`, so look for an function called `fetchAssoc();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it by changing the `fetch_style` of `fetchAll()`:

`$row= $searchElem->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

currently `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` is used by default

and you will get all values 2 times `indexed and assoc`

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked fine. And i got one more question. Can we create a csv file from php itself? i mean currently i am creating a csv file manually and exporting data to it. I want to create  file from php itself. Is it possible?

Comment: @Krischal Mahat Mh dont understand, you are creating a csv file from php with just 3 functions `fopen,fputscsv,fclose` and one `foreach` loop from given data. What do you mean? Everthing else would be `manually` because you can create an variable with csv content and write it with file_put_contents, but there you have to handle delimter and other stuff by yourself.